# Homebrew doctor is foreshadowing some sinister problems

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew, command-line-tool

I'm trying get Homebrew working with Xcode Command Line Tools, and they seem to be having it out with each other... In the words of Rodney King, "Can't we all just get along?"

For some background, when I first got my Mac about a year ago, I had no idea what I was doing. I was also using macports, which was, as the Homebrew website seems to be cognizant, driving me to become a raging alcoholic. As a result, my `/usr/local` directory got wayyy f-ed up. Eventually, gcc and g++ stopped working, and a lot of other things were breaking. So I did a clean install of OS X, and I want my shiny new installation to stay a little more organized.

Now, I've installed Apple's Command Line Tools, and all the binaries/libraries/etc have ended up in `/usr/local`. That's fine, but then I try to install homebrew, and it's also putting everything in the /usr/local/ directory. When I run the command

```
brew doctor
```

I get the following output (actually, this is just a snippet, but it captures the general spirit of what Homebrew is telling me):

```
Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libatomic.a
    /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.a
    /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a
    /usr/local/lib/libgomp.a
    /usr/local/lib/libitm.a
    /usr/local/lib/libmpc.a
    /usr/local/lib/libmpfr.a
    /usr/local/lib/libquadmath.a
    /usr/local/lib/libssp.a
    /usr/local/lib/libssp_nonshared.a
    /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.a
    /usr/local/lib/libsupc++.a
```

I thought I might place Homebrew in a different directory; however, the Homebrew documentation specifically warned against this. They say:

"Do yourself a favor and install to `/usr/local`. Some things may not build when installed elsewhere. One of the reasons Homebrew just works relative to the competition is because we recommend installing to `/usr/local`. Pick another prefix at your peril!"

The whole point is that I don't want to bother with micro-managing every package I install, and I don't want my filesystem to become an ungodly mess either. Anyone have any suggestions? Do I move command line tools to a different directory and add this to my $PATH? Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm, macports installs into `/opt/local` and the Xcode command line tools into `/usr/bin`, so I think you are getting confused somewhere.

Comment: You are correct about macports: the problem I've described above didn't exist with macports, but for reasons I haven't mentioned macports was still giving me trouble. Homebrew seems like a better option, but they insist that this claim is based on installing in /usr/local. Also, Xcode has installed in /usr/local/bin, not /usr/bin. Should I just move everything over to /usr? Or will that screw up all the linking and so on?

Comment: Well I have a sneaking suspicion you are blaming macports for problems you caused yourself.  As I say, it installs everything in `/opt/local`, and not `/usr/local` and if there are files in there, which could be because you didn't format your drive when re-installing OSX, I would suspect *you* put them there as I cannot think of another way they would get there.  So I think you should dial-down the anti-macports rhetoric.

Comment: OK, whatever happened was definitely due to my own ignorance and not macports. Still, this doesn't help with the problem...

Comment: I don't know about Homebrew, as I don't use it, however you could probably just dump the whole of `/usr/local` and re-install it.  However I am concerned that you think the Xcode command line tools were installed into `/usr/local` as that's not where they normally go.  Please confirm with `which clang` and post the response from `$(which clang) --version` (or at least ensure it has "Apple" in the version string).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I downloaded the "most recent" compilers from here: http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ . They are what got installed to `/usr/local/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a warning, and the message says why.  If you later want to install a Homebrew formula that installs one of those files, it will fail, because it will decline to overwrite those files, and then you will have to delete those files, as the message says.

Specifically, those files appear to belong to an installation of gcc.  You might want to research or try to remember why that was installed there.  It's probably OK to just delete them and install gcc from Homebrew if you need it.